# How do I transfer items between characters?

Tags: cube-world

In Cube world you get a lot of class specific drops that you can't use. Is it possible to transfer good items to one of your alternative characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create a new world for item exchange (*not required but makes life easier*)
2. Drop the equipment you want to transfer away from *Character A* on the ground at the spawn point (or some other easily recognisable point).
3. Quit to the main menu
4. Enter the same "transfer world" with *Character B* and pick them up from the ground.

For video demonstrations of the above, see [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEN9naysGrc) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VspaM6I4iDM).

Comment: I'd like to make a point once the housing system is available this answer will no longer be needed. It's the only way to transfer items now (unless you do it the multiplayer way), but in the future this will not be the case. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

launch the game twice on your computer and launch the server and meet up and exchange items